# iexpress resulting executable not a valid win32 application on XP

Tags: iexpress

I'm using the 32-bit iexpress.exe found in c:\windows\syswow64.  The resulting .exe file is fine on Windows 7 and Windows 8 (x64) where I can confirm it is a 32-bit app.   However when trying to run that on XP, it won't, claiming that it's not a valid Win32 application.

The only similar complaints I can find are for running iexpress .exe's on Win2000.

Don't have a 32-bit Windows 7 or 8 to use to check with.  I can use iexpress on XP to create the package, but that version doesn't do one particular thing that the newer versions on 7/8 do that I really want, so hoping to find a solution with the newer iexpress.

Comment: It probably is not compatible with Win XP at all. Its modified date says 2012, meaning it was probably recompiled and has dependencies on Win 7/8 which are not available on Win XP.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in `express.exe` on Windows 8 / Server 2012. The self extracting packages has dependencies to `msvcrt` (function `memcpy_s` and `except_handler4_common`) which is not available in `mcvcrt.dll` on Windows XP SP3.
Error has been fixed by Microsoft in Windows Server 2012 R2.